# Spring create scoped proxy bean programmatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, spring-aop

In `spring` is possible to define scoped proxy bens as described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-meta-annotations):

```
@Service
@SessionScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyBeanClass {
    // ...
}
```

I really would love to do the same thing **programatically**, e.g. when registering a bean with an `ApplicationContextInitializer`.

```
public class MyInitializer implements 
    ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericWebApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        applicationContext.registerBean(MyBeanClass.class, beanDefinitionCustomizer -> ....);
    }
}
```

Is this possible? I haven't found any public API to do so...

Comment: Have a look at `org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor`